# Deploy an Azrue VM from an ARM template via Powershell Runbook without downloading template

Tags: azure, powershell, templates, arm, runbook

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/automation/automation-deploy-template-runbook) article shows a tutorial how to deploy some resources from ARM templates in a powershell runbook. And as I understand, it will download the template and the parameters files in the specific path. But how can that work in an automated Runbook without having any directly attached storage to the automation account. Obviously, I'm misunderstanding something...

I mean the `Get-AzureStorageFileContent` command:

```
# Create a new context
$Context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName - 
StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

Get-AzureStorageFileContent -ShareName 'resource-templates' -Context 
$Context -path 'TemplateTest.json' -Destination 'C:\Temp'

$TemplateFile = Join-Path -Path 'C:\Temp' -ChildPath $StorageFileName

# Deploy the storage account
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName - 
TemplateFile $TemplateFile -TemplateParameterObject $Parameters
```

Do you know how to understand this, or are there some better methods to reach the goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-TemplateParameterUri` and `-TemplateUri` and give publicly available urls that where the tempaltes are stored.

Comment: These parameters seem to fix my problem. Unfortunately, the Uri's of my templates in Azure Storage don't work. Do I have to provide the raw link to the file, or just like in this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-powershell-sas-token#provide-sas-token-during-deployment) Well, I tried both no one worked, so my problems isn't fixed yet.

Comment: this is a different problem. I suggest you accept this answer and raise a new question